# how to generate scripts commands dynamically while creating package.json using npm init

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to put custom script commands while creating package.json using `npm init`.

npm init only offers to set **test** command but i want to set build, publish, release etc custom commands.

Basically i want to create below file using `npm init` without any manual intervention

```
 {
  "name": "some name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "release": "node release.js",
    "build": "node index.js"
   }
 }
```

**Note** : Guys i am aware than i can create package.json and then inside that i can edit manually script section to put my commands.

Comment: Does my answer solved your problem ? If yes please, mark it as solved. To help the rest of the community

Answer (score 0):

Referring to official doc, you can't do it directly.

But maybe, with using custom questions, it can works.

Have a look here https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file